# Abort has been called after passing socket to a different function

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio

I am new to C++ and networking, please excuse my stupidness.

I am trying to set up a TCP/IP server & client using Boost Asio for my game BattleShip. I have a function named `play_sockets()` in my class `Game`, which creates an active socket and then using `std::thread` and `std::move()`, I pass the socket to another function in the class named `play_game_s()`.

After the first write call or as soon as the connection is established in `play_game_s()`, I get the dialog box saying:

> abort() has been called

Surprisingly, if I ignore the error and continue taking input coordinates from the server (player 1) and then from the client (player 2), the connection is alive and is still transferring data back and forth. My assumption was that if I am receiving this `abort() has been called`, it means the connection shouldn't be active anymore. Can someone please explain why this is happening? And how can I resolve this issue?

If I combine the `play_sockets()` and `play_game_s()` into one function, it works without a problem, but because I would like to set up player 2's fleet for the game directly from the client, I am trying to learn and understand the passing of sockets from one function to another.

At the end, my goal is to use Create Socket -> Move Socket to Play_Game { do some read write } -> Move Socket to Init_Fleet { do some read write } -> Move Socket back to Play_Game.

If my approach to tackling this issue is totally wrong, please provide some guidance on what to fix. I am sharing the snippet of my `play_sockets()` and `play_game_s()` below here. Full code: https://replit.com/@Kd2maru/BattleShip

```cpp
void Game::play_sockets() {
    boost::asio::io_context m_io_context;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint ep(boost::asio::ip::address_v4::any(), 54000);
    // Step 3. Instantiating and opening an acceptor socket.
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor(m_io_context, ep.protocol());
    // Step 4. Binding the acceptor socket to the server endpoint.
    acceptor.bind(ep);
    // Step 5. Starting to listen for incoming connection requests.
    acceptor.listen();
    // Step 6. Creating an active socket.
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket m_socket(m_io_context);
    // Step 7. Processing the next connection request and connecting the active socket to the client.
    acceptor.accept(m_socket);
    //all steps for creating socket using boost::asio are done.
    //Now perform read write operations in a function.
    std::thread( & Game::play_game_s, this, std::move(m_socket));
}

void Game::play_game_s(ip::tcp::socket && sock) {
    Input_Coordinates ic;
    while (is_winner()) {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << setw(25) << "Player 1 Board:\n";
        write_data(ss, sock);
        std::stringstream().swap(ss);
        ss = player1 -> display_board(true);
        write_data(ss, sock);
        std::stringstream().swap(ss);
        ss << setw(25) << "Player 2 Board:\n";
        write_data(ss, sock);
        std::stringstream().swap(ss);
        ss = player2 -> display_board(true);
        write_data(ss, sock);
        cout << "(Player 1 turn) ";
        std::stringstream().swap(ss);
        ss << "(Player 1 turn) ";
        write_data(ss, sock);
        do {
            cin >> ic.x;
            cin >> ic.y;
        } while (player1 -> is_not_tried(ic));
        player2 -> attack(ic);
        cout << setw(25) << "Player 2 Board: \n";
        std::stringstream().swap(ss);
        ss << setw(25) << "Player 2 Board:\n";
        write_data(ss, sock);
        std::stringstream().swap(ss);
        ss = player2 -> display_board(true);
        write_data(ss, sock);
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting that in a debugger allows you to inspect the stack trace at the point of error:

```
Thread 1 "Server" received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
__GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51
51      ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: Bestand of map bestaat niet.
(gdb) bt
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51
#1  0x00007ffff71de921 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:79
#2  0x00007ffff7a630a9 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#3  0x00007ffff7a6e506 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#4  0x00007ffff7a6e571 in std::terminate() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#5  0x00005555555704a7 in std::thread::~thread (this=0x7fffffffd028, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/c++/10/thread:157
#6  0x0000555555567a54 in Game::play_sockets (this=0x7fffffffd7d0) at /home/sehe/Projects/BattleShips/Game.cpp:272
#7  0x0000555555565ed3 in Game::start_game (this=0x7fffffffd7d0) at /home/sehe/Projects/BattleShips/Game.cpp:47
#8  0x000055555556321e in main () at /home/sehe/Projects/BattleShips/main.cpp:7
```

As you can see, the thread destructor is complaining that it hasn't been joined:

> If `*this` has an associated thread (`joinable() == true`), `std::terminate()` is called.

You should keep the threads so they can be joined. Or you should consider using async IO - the strong point of using Asio to begin with.